# Beginner exercise : Design a Money class

Tags: c++, class, currency

I'm actually learning the C++ programming language (I have never programmed before) and I'm trying to solve a problem where I have to design and implement a simple money class for calculations involving dollars. The author gives me some rules to follow about how to implement this class :

- Represent a monetary amount as a number of cents in a long int.
- For input and output represent the result in dollar and cents e.g 16.45
- arithmetic operations need to be accurate to the last cent using the 4/5 rounding rule.

After some researches made before coding I found out that double types are not recommended for monetary amounts and that I should integers. My question is about how can I read a double as input and converting it into a long int without losing data ? Should I use some other way/types to do this ?  Should I take long int(representing cents) as constructor arguments directly for this class ? I have been searching but I found a lot of informations about a possible loss of data that just confused me. This is a beginner exercise so I don't think that calculations should be very precise. Thank you

Comment: Once you read a **double** you have already lost data. Typically you can `round` it (typical approach is multiplying by 100 and then round it into an integer). You should either do that or read as a string and parse it yourself into a lossless data model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that the input will be well formatted.

That is, all monetary amounts you receive will be in the form of

```
99.99
```

Where the `9` symbols could be any digit between 0 and 9 inclusive. On the left hand side of the decimal point, there will only be digits, and the range will be small enough to be stored within an `int`.

The right hand side of the decimal point (and there will always be a decimal point) will always be a positive number that also fits within an `int`.

You can create a very simple structure to represent a monetary amount, separating dollars into one `int`, and cents into another:

```
struct Money
{
    int dollars;
    int cents;
};
```

Upon reading in an amount, you will first read in the `dollars` field. Then you will read in a `.`. Then you will read in the `cents` field:

```
Money m;
char c;
std::cin >> m.dollars >> c >> m.cents;
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6c9fac2e1c74625b)

After you have this much figured out, you can start to make your I/O more robust, handling cases where there is no decimal point, or someone put in a really large number. At that point, it may be reasonable to first read into a `std::string` to get a textual representation of your money, and from there parse the `string`:

```
Money m{0,0};
std::string text;
std::getline(std::cin, text);
std::cout << "Input was: " << text << std::endl;

// is there a decimal point?
size_t decimal_point_position = text.find_first_of('.');
m.dollars = stoi(text.substr(0, decimal_point_position));
if (decimal_point_position != std::string::npos)
{
    decimal_point_position += 1;
    m.cents = stoi(text.substr(decimal_point_position, text.size() - decimal_point_position));
}
```

[Demo2](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77a8621cc32595d1)

And from there you can continue to improve the robustness of the input. What if there are two decimal places? What if there's characters in the input?

I suggest you write a couple of tests to test as many possibilities of input as possible, assuming the dumbest, most computer-illiterate user ever. How should you handle invalid input? Ask for more, throw an exception, use a default value and print a warning? All these are decisions you'll make in the future when handling user input.

Edit:
To address your last point

> arithmetic operations need to be accurate to the last cent using the 4/5 rounding rule.

This will in general not be too difficult, only tedious. The biggest hurdle you will run into will be division. At this point you need to be very careful with integer rounding. That is:

`2/1` will produce `0`, not `0.5`.

The multiplication and division operations should not be implemented, as they don't make sense. Search the web to see how you can accurately round with integer division.

Comment: After you get more advanced, you may want to look into `std::ratio`[http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/ratio/ratio] for representing the `cents` portion as a fraction of 100.

Comment: thank you very much. I was having some problems in understanding how to implement the class and your answer was of great help for me. I couldn't understand how to implement everything with a single long int variable, but as I can see your solution is the best for me. I think that the author could have been more clear with his problem statement in the book.